# Is there a way on Jenkins to check if my Java code is google style formatted and only pass the build if the formatting is correct?

Tags: java, jenkins

Is there a way on Jenkins to check if my code is google style formatted and only pass the build if the formatting is correct? I am using google style formatting but currently haven't found a good answer about this anywhere

Comment: Where have you looked?

Comment: Code formatting and auditing is inherently programming-language-specific endeavour whereas Jenkins is a programming-language-agnostic engine for automatic building and testing which you have to set up for your specific language and project. The question is therefore incomplete.

Comment: basically I am trying to stop people from pushing unformatted code in my branch. Is there a check I can do for that? @V-R

Comment: @Michael I have looked at different sources. Could you suggest any source you believe its useful please?

Comment: If you are working with java - just a guess - you might want to try [checkstyle](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle) but I don't know how good it is compared to others. Jenkins is agnostic of your choice of tools and can be used with pretty much any of them. Please add a tag to your question, corresponding to the programming language - the answer will depend on that: e.g. for python code you would need another style checker.

Comment: What you want is a pre-check-in hook that will make sure your code meets your style guidelines BEFORE it is committed to the repo or merged to your master branch. Failing a build instead is too late in the process. Tools will vary depending on language, IDE and VC tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maven checkstyle (or findbugs) plugin can report violations, jenkins warnings-ng can generate report (and I hope mark build as failed).

Comment: Hey @y_ug thanks for the response. Could you refer me to an easy to follow tutorial please?

Comment: @manzk warnings-ng documentation (https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-ng-plugin/blob/master/doc/Documentation.md) has examples for checkStyle